# Can I create a custom Seekbar without a drawable resource

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

I have created a custom SeekBar which uses a LayerList. I haven't used a drawable resource.

It says [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) that my "item"...

> Drawable resource. **Required**. Reference to a drawable resource.

Will I encounter any problems if I do not create a drawable resource for this item?

**custom_seek_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/bkg">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/prog">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="12dp" />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs says:

A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other drawables.

The equivalent of  in Java code is the Layer Drawable.
( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html )

So it will probably not accept it without the resources. It was really a bad idea to give such a generic name (layer-list) to something related only to drawables.

Hope that it helps!

Comment: What do you mean by? "So it will probably not accept it without the resources"